# How upload video with call to action button on Facebook Page in php

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to upload video on Facebook page with call to action button and link in Facebook php sdk but its not upload with call to action here below is my code

```
 if ($token) {
     $this->fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);
     if ($args["img"]) {
        $linkData = ["source" => $args["img"], "message" => $args["post"]];
        $this->fb->post('/' . $user_details[0]->net_id . '/feed', $linkData, $token);
        return true;
     }  elseif ($args["video"]) {
        $linkData = ["source" => $this->fb->videoToUpload($args["video"]), "title" => $args["post"], "call_to_action" => array("type" => "SHOP_NOW", "value" => array("link" => "http://example.com"))];
        $this->fb->post('/' . $user_details[0]->net_id . '/videos', $linkData, $token);
        return true;
    } elseif ($args["url"]) {
        $linkData = ["link" => $args["url"], "message" => $args["post"]];
        $this->fb->post('/' . $user_details[0]->net_id . '/feed', $linkData, $token);
        return true;
    } else {
        $linkData = ["message" => $args["post"]];
        $this->fb->post('/' . $user_details[0]->net_id . '/feed', $linkData, $token);
        return true;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: We have a similar question. We need to upload a video on facebook with a post title that has an external link, like this page: https://www.facebook.com/Blitzquotidiano/videos/10154163072676406/